# Change Lookup Column target SharePoint 2010 manually

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, lookup-column

- I have three lists **A, B & C**.
- List **A** have the lookup columns and existing List Template.
- List A have two  lookup columns,which are pointing to List B & C's columns.
- How to edit the column in List A and change the lookup Target / source in SharePoint 2010?
- Is it possible?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46093/change-the-source-on-a-lookup-column)

Comment: This one is not manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to delete the existing lookup list column and you have to create new lookup column.

Comment: Is there way instead of deleting the column & recreate the columns?

Comment: No. there is no other way around as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried it yet, but I have the same requirement, so I'll be doing it soon.
https://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2013/12/sharepoint-repair-lookup-columns-which-are-not-connected-to-a-list/