# change target list of Lookup field from UI

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint list with a lookup field, is it possible to change the target list fro UI? I don't have access to Powershell

[image]

Any thoughts how I could change the field without delete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, There is no way to change the `Get Information` list of Lookup field through UI.

**The available options are**

- Delete and recreate it again, in case it's a new column.
- In case it's not a new column, Try to create a new column with the required list then updated its value using a workflow then delete old one
- You can update the SPField Schema XML directly, for example using JS Object Model as mentioned at [Change the source on a lookup column?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46093/change-the-source-on-a-lookup-column) (I don't think it's a good practice)

Comment: I Agree. JSOM is not a good approach as it can break the list very easily if the new schema that is used in the schema has even an extra character.

Answer (score 3):

You can test out the below JSOM code in a Content Editor Webpart. I have tested and it successfully changes the lookup list. But you will have to do further testing to ensure that nothing else is broken. This code directly changes the **list field schema** from client side which is not really a good approach as even the slightest error can make the list useless. Suggested approach would still be **PowerShell** Or **Field Recreation**.

The parameters :

*fromList* - Current List where look up field is present

*fromField*  - LookUp field name

*toListId* - The New LookUp List guid which you can get as mentioned [here](https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2008/04/29/finding-the-id-guid-for-a-sharepoint-list/)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(updateWebSite, "sp.js");

});
var oWebsite ;

function updateWebSite() {
var fromList = 'Check List';
var fromField = 'LookUpColumn';
var toListId = '{82b5a10b-f263-4b69-a67b-105d73dce817}';
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var field = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(fromList).get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(fromField);

ctx.load(field);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
var schema = field.get_schemaXml();
schema = schema.replace(/list=\"\S*\"/i, '').replace(/\/\>/, 'List="' + toListId + '" />');

field.set_schemaXml(schema);
ctx.executeQueryAsync();
});

}
</script>
```

The above code changed the look up list from **Approval List** to **Accordion**

**Before running the script :**
[image]

**After running the script :**

[image]

[Reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46093/change-the-source-on-a-lookup-column)